# RestKit force CoreData save

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an `RKEntityMapping` with `identificationAttributes`. Is it possible to force a save to CoreData during a GET, even if nothing in the data from the server has changed? I want that because I have a `willSave:` method in my model class that updates a `lastUpdated` timestamp. This should be updated even if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the response has been mapped RestKit passes all of the mapped objects back to you via its success callbacks so you can iterate through the objects and update them or call methods on the context.

Comment: I do it in the success callback now (dropping the willSave idea). Thanks for the help.